# How to verify the prediction (k-NN-model) with accuracy-formula?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I need to complete the code and create a function to calculate the accuracy of my model using test data compared to predicted data. The predictions mode have been solved within another code.

The input I have to give is the accuracy formula. See the picture ([Here, Accuracy-formula)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqrm2.png) for the formula.

My current code and where I am struck is at the accuracy-formula:

```
acc = ((1/predictions) * ((np.sum(predictions == y_test[:]))))

return acc


k = 25
 
accuracy = calculate_accuracy(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, k)

print("Accuracy of the model is {:.3f}.".format(accuracy))"
```

Whereas I should make the comparison between "predictions" vs "y_test" and the calculation should be done by: number of correct predictions divided by number of predictions. But I do now know how to make it happen in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the classifiers score to determine accuracy.  It should match your function.  The model is 98% accurate

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
X=iris.data
y=iris.target

df=pd.DataFrame(X,columns=iris.feature_names)
print(df.head(5))
 knn = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto',
                         leaf_size=30,
                         metric='minkowski',
                         metric_params=None,
                         n_jobs=1,
                         n_neighbors=25,
                         p=1,
                         weights='uniform')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=21, stratify=y)

knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
train_accuracy = knn.score(X_train, y_train)

plt.title('k-NN: Varying Number of Neighbors')
plt.plot(neighbors, test_accuracy, label = 'Testing Accuracy')
plt.plot(neighbors, train_accuracy, label = 'Training Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Number of Neighbors')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()

y_pred=knn.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))

print("Manual Accuracy",sum(y_pred==y_test)/len(y_test))
```